# Basemaps are blurry/pixelated in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, basemap, pixel

I recently migrated from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro and I am having trouble with the clarity of the basemap (whether World_Hillshade or World_Shaded_relief): It appears pixelated/blurry.

I have imported the map from an ArcMap .mxd but adding a new basemap doesnt help. The rendering quality is set to high, and exporting the map as an image still shows the same issue.

Comment: Edit your question to show the difference between arcmap vs. arcpro

Comment: There are a lot of variables here, down to the exact OS, graphics card, and drivers. Esri Tech Support is more likely to be able to help than StackExchange.